# Php - stored procedure return value issue

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo

I am trying to call a MS SQL stored procedure form php.
I have tested the stored procedure by itself in management studio with hard coded parameters and was able to get it to execute with the expected results.

Here i am getting the error while trying to fetch the data from Stored procedure. As per my observation, If stored procedure taking more than 3 seconds, i am getting the error. I mean return value is nothing. If Store procedure takes 2/3 seconds it is working fine. How can i buffer some time for executing the Store procedure. Please check the below code.

```
$tsql = "EXEC rrproc_get__all__search_test ?, ?, ?, ?, ?";

$countResumes = $sqlserver_db->prepare($tsql);

$countResumes->bindParam(1, $time, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$countResumes->bindParam(2, $getKeywords, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$countResumes->bindParam(3, $s1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$countResumes->bindParam(4, $s2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$countResumes->bindParam(5, $m, PDO::PARAM_INT);


$countResumes->execute();

// Get the number of rows returned. 
$totalRows = $countResumes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Comment: Are you running on Windows and getting PDO using the SqlSrv driver?  Also what version of SQL server?

Comment: @ficuscr, Exactly. Sql server 2012

Comment: Sorry, should have asked first, what is the error?

Comment: @ficuscr, This is the error page after executing  SP.500 - Internal server error.

Comment: Look in your web server logs.  Usually more info will be available other than the generic Internal Server Error.  Or try to catch an exception and use whatever the ` get_last_error_message ` method is called.  Are any of your .ini settings insanely low... what is it `mssql,timeout` maybe?  Without an an error message its hard to offer much more.  Assume its not lack of `ANSI_NULLS` or `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`?

Comment: @ficuscr, Thanks for your response. I ll check and update you.